# how to include Azure Devops CMMI template Risk element into Scrum Template

Tags: azure-devops, scrum, azure-boards, cmmi

Is there any opportunity of include the Risk Work Item used in Azure DevOps CMMI template, into an already created Scrum template project???

If not, can I create my own customized work items? as for ex. Risks?

Answer (score 0):

You can't 'clone' the Risk work item from CMMI to Scrum, but you can recreate it with the same fields.

The docs walk you through the process:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/customize-process

Basic steps:

1. Create a inherited process under the scrum process
2. Create a new Work Item Type in the inherited process
3. Add all the fields from the Risk work item type
4. Assign the process to the project